# Salesforce upgrade with website only

Tags: professional-edition, editions

I'm trying to upgrade from Essentials to Professional with Web API, but store.salesforce.com doesn't seem to have the Professional option.  Is there any way to do that from the website or API or do I need to get on the phone with somebody?

Comment: As in you're trying to upgrade your org edition? Pretty sure you need to contact your Account Executive for that. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I am coming to that conclusion too, thanks :)